# Swift / UICollectionView / Share Button in cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController, with a UICollectionView with a (custom) UIButton at the reusableViewCell.

I have the following code for a TableView

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let shareRaceAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Share") {
        (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

        let sheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Teilen mit", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let race = self.races[indexPath.row]

        //
        let twAction = self.newAction(SLServiceTypeTwitter, race: race)
        sheet.addAction(twAction)

        //
        let fbAction = self.newAction(SLServiceTypeFacebook, race: race)
        sheet.addAction(fbAction)

        //
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        sheet.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can this Code be implemented for a UICollectionView with a custom button?
Help is very appreciated

Comment: I believe there is some tutorials on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com). Unfortunately the website is undergoing maintenance right now.

Comment: You'll find the UICollectionView works pretty much the same as a UITableVIew, just with some different names.

Comment: self.presentViewController(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil) does not work and that is the line, that calls the pop up